# Cant set a cookie from a wordpress plugin on a specific site

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

My wordpress plugin sets a cookie like:

```
setcookie($key,json_encode($something),0,'/');
```

Which usually works, but doesn't work for a specific user's website.
Doing `var_dump($_COOKIES);` right after the `setcookie()` call shows that the relevant cookie is present in the array, but there is no setcookie in the response headers. Other cookies set on the public side of the website(not admin dashboard) that should be set by my plugin don't work either.

The user has a caching plugin installed but this problem is presisting even if the page request doesn't hit any cache at all.

Setting a testing cookie from the `functions.php` file in the active theme works.

What could be causing the problem and what could be some potential solutions to this or ways to debug this further?

Answer (score 0):

Code placed elsewhere in the site like functions.php or the wordpress core could be modifying the headers before the response goes back to the browser.

Try setting the cookie, then dumping the cookie, and then die, then view the browsers response headers:

```php
setcookie($key,json_encode($something),0,'/');
var_dump($_COOKIES);
die();
```

If it works as intended, you could move the `die();` portion further along in the code execution until you find the conflicting code.

Otherwise a better way in php development would be to use PHP Exception breakpoints﻿ in JetBrains IDE where you can add breakpoints, and at each breakpoint you can see the php superglobal variables like $_COOKIE

Comment: I was also thinking that the cookies were probably being modified somewhere down the line, but, interestingly enough `die()`ing after the setcookie call doesnt set the cookie either. What else could it be?

Comment: Also, because the problem is happening on a webiste of a user of my plugin, I am unable to connect my IDE to it or use debugging tools